# Playing audio from a Hyper-V VM to its host (or any network device)

Tags: networking, audio, virtual-machine

I understand Hyper-V does not provide audio virtualization. Is there any way, even through 3rd-party software, to install a virtual driver that can transport audio to a networked device? The receiving device could be the Hyper-V host (via virtual network adapter) or a networked amplifier.
I have been playing around with [JackAudio](https://jackaudio.org/) and [VBCable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) without much success thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not very likely possible (95% or greater).

You need to be able to run your Guest as a Generaion 2 guest. You cannot switch between Generation 1 and Generation 2. This is establish when you make the VM and cannot be switched.

Once Generation 2 you can turn on Enhanced Session Mode in Hyper-V Settings (Hyper-V Manager App) and see if you can attach a USB device or a dongle.

Then see if you can enable Audio Services.

Please see this article:

[Hyper-V Additional Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enhanced-session-mode)

> Share audio devices (speakers and microphones)
>
> By default, virtual machines using enhanced session mode pass audio
> through so you can hear audio from the virtual machine. The virtual
> machine will use the audio device currently selected on the host
> machine.
>
> To change those settings or to add microphone passthrough (so you can
> record audio in a virtual machine):
>
> Select the "Settings..." menu for configuring remote audio settings
>
> Now configure audio and microphone settings
>
> Since your virtual machine is probably running locally, the "play on
> this computer" and "play on remote computer" options will yield the
> same results.

Overall Audio usually does not work in Hyper-V machines that I have used and tried.

You might consider VMware Workstation Pro V17 as it is much more flexible. I have VMware on one machine and Hyper-V on the other manchine.

Comment: Thank you. I tried all possibilities and nothing works robustly. I can make some stuff work, but latencies are horrible and audio is often disrupted. My conclusion is that Hyper-V is just not made for that.

Comment: Yes. Hyper-V is pretty much for bare bones operating systems.  I use VMware as a much friendlier virtualization App

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [VBCable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) as audio driver and [Sonobus](https://www.sonobus.net/) for audio broadcasting over LAN . This works fine for me [Setting Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh95Y.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).